# Using MST Mass Email appexchange package with custom object

Tags: appexchange, mass-email

Im trying to us the great MST Mass email package, but having trouble getting it to work as i would expect.

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B5ESSEA3

I have a custom object that has a lookup field which points at contacts.  What I want to setup as a mass email button on the custom objects list view.

I set up a new "settings" in the MST settings tab setting the custom object to Invitations__c and the Contact field to Nominator__c which save ok.

Then i setup a visual force page that just has this on it

```
<apex:page standardController="Invitation__c" recordSetVar="contacts" extensions="MSTMassEmail.MassEmailController">
 <apex:pageMessages />
 <MSTMassEmail:MassEmailComponent Setting="Invitations"/>
</apex:page>
```

I was able to add a custom list view button that works but when i got to save it looks like its trying to send to the invitation ids instead of the nominator ids because it says

SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_ID_FIELD, Only Users, Contacts, Leads, and Person objects are allowed for targetObjectIds.: []

Im thinking of writing a custom extension that would pull the contacts from the invitations but not sure if theres a more built in way?

Comment: any luck with this? I am coming up with the same problem. Thanks, Vicki

Comment: Sadly no luck so far